# Customer Listener added through config

Tags: quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

I wrote the below custom job listener.
(Not a very robust one).

Is there a way to wire up this listener through .config
(in the  element to be more specific)

"GranadaCoder.Apps.QuartzPOC.BAL.Listeners.MyFirstJobListener, GranadaCoder.Apps.QuartzPOC"

The followup question is .. can you add more than one custom JobListener?

I see the object-model (C#) code.
I just don't see it through .config.

```
IJobListener jobListener001 = new MyFirstJobListener ();
sched.ListenerManager.AddJobListener(jobListener001, GroupMatcher<JobKey>.AnyGroup());
```

Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Common.Logging;
using Quartz;

/* Assembly Name = "GranadaCoder.Apps.QuartzPOC" */
namespace GranadaCoder.Apps.QuartzPOC.BAL.Listeners
{
    public class MyFirstJobListener : IJobListener
    {
        public void JobExecutionVetoed(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {

            string msg = string.Format("    MyFirstJobListener : JobExecutionVetoed fired.  Key = '{0}'.", context.JobDetail.Key);

            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyFirstJobListener));
            log.Info(msg);

        }

        public void JobToBeExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context)
        {
            string msg = string.Format("    MyFirstJobListener : JobToBeExecuted fired.  Key = '{0}'.", context.JobDetail.Key);

            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyFirstJobListener));
            log.Info(msg);
        }

        public void JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException)
        {
            string msg = string.Format("    MyFirstJobListener : JobWasExecuted fired.  Key = '{0}'.", context.JobDetail.Key);

            Console.WriteLine(msg);
            ILog log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(MyFirstJobListener));
            log.Info(msg);

            if (null != jobException)
            {

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                Exception exc = jobException;
                while (null != exc)
                {
                    sb.Append(exc.Message + " --- ");
                    exc = exc.InnerException;
                }

                string sbMsg = sb.ToString();
                msg = string.Format("    MyFirstJobListener : JobWasExecuted fired.  jobException.Message = '{0}'.", sbMsg);
                Console.WriteLine(msg);
                log.Info(msg);

            }
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get 
            {
                return "    MyFirstJobListener : MyFirstJobListener.Name Property";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I figured out a few things.

There are 2 "built in" listeners.

You can wire those up.  And get basic "ILog" events.

What threw me off was the 2 names "triggHistory" and "jobHistory".

These are arbitrary.  "triggHistory" does not exist in the source code.

So you have to do two things.
Implement the interface of the listener you're interested in AND you implement "ISchedulerPlugin".
(The "ISchedulerPlugin" is what was illuding me)

Example:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class MySuperCoolJobListener : IJobListener, ISchedulerPlugin
  { /* bunch of stuff */ }


  public class MySuperCoolTriggerListener : ITriggerListener, ISchedulerPlugin
  { /* bunch of stuff */ }

  public class MySuperCoolSchedulerListener : ISchedulerListener , ISchedulerPlugin
  { /* bunch of stuff */ }

}
```

THEN you can add them to the .config(uration).

```
<add key="quartz.plugin.WhateverNameIWantHereJobHistory.type" value="MyNamespace.MySuperCoolJobListener, MyAssembly" />
<add key="quartz.plugin.WhateverNameIWantHereTriggerHistory.type" value="MyNamespace.MySuperCoolTriggerListener, MyAssembly" />
<add key="quartz.plugin.WhateverNameIWantHereSchedulerHistory.type" value="MyNamespace.MySuperCoolSchedulerListener, MyAssembly" />
```

And you can add more than one "set".

```
<add key="quartz.plugin.PooptyDoopJobHistory.type" value="MyNamespace.MyTotallyRadJobListener, MyOtherAssembly" />
<add key="quartz.plugin.PooptyDoopTriggerHistory.type" value="MyNamespace.MyTotallyRadTriggerListener, MyOtherAssembly" />
<add key="quartz.plugin.PooptyDoopSchedulerHistory.type" value="MyNamespace.MyTotallyRadSchedulerListener, MyOtherAssembly" />
```

The value for the DotNetAssembly is important of course.

The prefix of "quartz.plugin." is the important thing.

But the value between "quartz.plugin." and ".type" is kinda arbitrary.
That was the monkey wrench.

Back to how it works:
The framework will try to instantiate them....

The quartz.net source code bread-crumbs are:

```
    public const string PropertyPluginPrefix = "quartz.plugin";
```

and

```
public class StdSchedulerFactory : ISchedulerFactory
{}
```

and

```
        // Set up any SchedulerPlugins
        // ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

        IList<string> pluginNames = cfg.GetPropertyGroups(PropertyPluginPrefix);
        ISchedulerPlugin[] plugins = new ISchedulerPlugin[pluginNames.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < pluginNames.Count; i++)
        {
            NameValueCollection pp = cfg.GetPropertyGroup("{0}.{1}".FormatInvariant(PropertyPluginPrefix, pluginNames[i]), true);

            string plugInType = pp[PropertyPluginType];

            if (plugInType == null)
            {
                initException = new SchedulerException("SchedulerPlugin type not specified for plugin '{0}'".FormatInvariant(pluginNames[i]));
                throw initException;
            }
            ISchedulerPlugin plugin;
            try
            {
                plugin = ObjectUtils.InstantiateType<ISchedulerPlugin>(LoadType(plugInType));
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                initException = new SchedulerException("SchedulerPlugin of type '{0}' could not be instantiated.".FormatInvariant(plugInType), e);
                throw initException;
            }
            try
            {
                ObjectUtils.SetObjectProperties(plugin, pp);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                initException = new SchedulerException("JobStore SchedulerPlugin '{0}' props could not be configured.".FormatInvariant(plugInType), e);
                throw initException;
            }
            plugins[i] = plugin;
        }
```

And if all that doesn't clear it up....then find this quartz.net code.

LoggingJobHistoryPlugin.cs

```
public class LoggingJobHistoryPlugin : ISchedulerPlugin, IJobListener
{
```

LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin.cs

```
public class LoggingTriggerHistoryPlugin : ISchedulerPlugin, ITriggerListener
{
```

(Quartz.Net didn't seem to write a default/included ISchedulerListener , fyi)

Clear as mud?